# Multiple Landsat 8 images shown for a single path, row, and date in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

I am trying to export an image above the Yenisei Delta using Google Earth Engine. I have its path, row, and date, and when I filter the Landsat 8 TOA imagecollection, I am able to find this image:

```
var path = 156  
var row = 10;
var date = ee.Date.fromYMD(2013,7,22);

var ic = l8.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', path))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', row))
  .filterDate(date, ee.Date(date).advance(1, 'day'));

var im = ic.first()

print(im)


var vizParams = {
  bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B3'],
  min: 0,
  max: 0.5,
  gamma: [0.95, 1.1, 1]
};

Map.addLayer(im, vizParams)
```

[GEE code here.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5735da55050fe3c56119c32280fbc9f7)

However, the map shows that there are three images (regions?) associated with this single image:
[image]
Closer inspection shows that 2. and 3. are the same image as 1, but projected incorrectly.

I am unable to export the image as it is too large (I did increase maxPixels). I exported a dozen or so others without problem.

**How do I separate the true image from the false ones for export?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw a polygon around the right an add it as a region parameter on your export:

```js
   Export.image.toDrive({
   image: yourexport,
   description: name,
   scale: 30, 
   maxPixels: 318651567139,
   region: geometry // the polygon added around the right image
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also filter by metadata, specifically using the row and path information. Within each image in the collection, the properties tab has a variety of parameters upon which you can filter your image collection. Here, you'd need WRS_ROW and WRS_PATH.

Try something like this:

```
var filteredData = imageCollection.filterMetadata('WRS_ROW', 'equals', 10)
.filterMetadata('WRS_PATH', 'equals', 156)
.filterDate('desired start date', 'desired end date')
print(filteredData)
```

I've never tried filtering on two metadata parameters at once, so if this doesn't work try filtering by row, then make a new variable upon which to filter by path.

Comment: The original post _is_ filtering on the path and row metadata already. And you can definitely filter on multiple metadata properties.